# Laravel does not authorize access to route

Tags: laravel

i defined abilities on a route:

`Route::get('check-table/{table}/{type}', 'TableController@checkTable')->can('view',[\App\Models\Table::class]);`

the logic behind is that the user requesting access to this route can only view the model, the controller method does not do operations other than View on the model but Laravel still not authorize the access. it shows this error :

> "message": "This action is unauthorized.", error code : 403

info: i'm using a gate to authorize access in the Form Request
is my usage of abilities applied on the route wrong ?

Comment: Can you include the code for abilities

Comment: ->can('view',[\App\Models\Table::class])

Comment: Are you using Policy ? Sanctum ? Gate ?

Comment: i am using Gate

Comment: Can you add the code ?